How does the "jidaigeki Japanese" used in Shogun differ from actual speech in the 1600s?
The dialog in the Shōgun series (2024) is supposedly in "old" Japanese, but here on Japanese.SE we know better: it's actually "jidaigeki Japanese" as spoken in Japanese period dramas, meaning pronounced like modern standard Japanese, but with some archaic/stereotypical vocabulary (拙者{せっしゃ}, 其方{そなた}, 忝{かたじけな}い) and verb endings (〜でござる, 〜まする, 〜ぬ).
But what did actual speech sound like in the early Edo era of the 1600s, and would it be comprehensible to a modern native speaker?  I'd be particularly keen to see some typical phrases rendered in modern Japanese, jidaigeki Japanese and early Edo Japanese.
To narrow this down a bit more, please assume an Edo dialect speaker of the samurai class (or any other convenient persona) and feel free to use IPA etc as needed to indicate where the sounds themselves have shifted.

A YouTube channel called minerva scientia offers videos simulating spoken Japanese from the Heian, Sengoku and Edo periods. I'm not sure how accurate they are from an academic standpoint, though.

As a side question… minerva scientiaのホストさんは何の生物っけ…日本の伝統の妖怪の一種かなって…

1600 is customary boundary between Late Middle Japanese (LMJ) (1200 - 1600) and Modern Japanese (NJ) (1600 -). (Political periods: Kamakura (1185 - 1333), Muromachi (1333 - 1573), Edo (1603 - 1868), Meiji (1868 - 1912))
Summary of phonological and grammatical differences between 1600 Japanese and 2024 Japanese:

In 1600 お and を were [wo]. [wo] changed to [o] somewhen during Edo period, and first attestations of romanization as "o" are from Thunberg (1792).

In 1600 え was [je]. It is often reconstructed that Old Japanese (700 - 800) and some earlier phase of Early Middle Japanese (800 - 1200) had separate [je] and [e] syllables, which merged into [je] during Early Middle Japanese. [je] changed to [e] during Meiji period (1868 - 1912). English spellings such as "Yedo" and "yen" come from time before this change.

In 1600, besides [o] and [oː] (high-mid back rounded vowel), there was 1 additional long vowel [ɔː] (low-mid back rounded vowel), which had no short equivalent, and developed from earlier monophthongization of diphthong. (Frellesvig (2010, pages 319-322).)
Portugese sources usually used "ǒ" for [ɔː] and "ô" for [oː] (besides e.g. "ǔ" for [uː]).
Monophthongizations of [Vu] diphthongs during Late Middle Japanese:
[au] → [ɔː]
[ou] → [oː]
[jeu] → [joː] (after consonants: [ʲeu] → [ʲoː])
[uu] → [uː]
[iu] → [juː] (after consonants: [ʲiu] → [ʲuː])
[ɔː] and [oː] merged into [oː] during early Edo period.
Aforementioned monophthongizations usually have not occurred across morpheme boundaries (or kanji boundaries), but there were exceptions:
3.1. Conclusive (終止形) and Attributive (連体形) of -w- verbs (Old Japanese -p-) underwent monophthongizations across stem-final w and suffix -u. Examples:
会ふ: OJ [apu] → (950-1000) [au] → LMJ [ɔː]
買ふ: OJ [kapu] → (950-1000) [kau] → LMJ [kɔː]
問ふ: OJ [topu] → (950-1000) [tou] → LMJ [toː]
Uncontracted forms of Conclusive (終止形) and Attributive (連体形) (e.g. [au ~ aɯ̟ᵝ], [kau ~ kaɯ̟ᵝ]) were restored later, under influence of other forms (e.g. negative, past) (e.g. standard Modern Japanese [awanai], [atta], [kawanai], [katta]), which never had phonological environment allowing for monophthongization.
3.2. Continuative (連用形) (also functioning as adverbial form) of verbal adjectives, after elision of k of suffix -ku (similarly to elision of k of Attributive (連体形) suffix -ki), underwent monophthongization. Examples:
高く: [takaku] → [takau] → [takɔː]
黑く: [kuroku] → [kurou] → [kuroː]
This change (elision of k of suffix -ku, followed by monophthongization) occurred at least in Kansai dialects, but maybe not in Edo dialect. Forms resulting from this change have been borrowed from Kansai dialects to standard Modern Japanese (based on Tokyo dialect) as so called polite forms of adjectives.

In 1600 weakening and deletion of word-final vowels [i], [u] was occurring in more phonological environments than in standard Modern Japanese.
Examples from Portuguese sources mentioned by Frellesvig (2010, pages 323):
fitotçu "one" → fitotç [ɸʲitot͡s]
axi no fara "reed plain" → ax no fara [aɕ no ɸaɾa]
gozaru "exist, polite" → gozar [ᵑgoⁿzaɾ]

In 1600 /i.a/ and /e.a/ were realized with palatal approximant [j] as onset of second syllable: [ija], [jeja] ~ [ʲeja].
Examples from Portuguese sources mentioned by Frellesvig (2010, pages 324):
miyacaxi [mʲijakaɕi] "votive light" (← /mi-akasi/ "HON-light")
caqeyǒ [kakʲejɔː] "matches, is equal to" (← /kake-au/)
cami-yǒta [kamʲijɔːta] "bit each other" (← /kami-auta/)

In 1600 voiced plosives and fricatives b, d, z, g were prenasalized: [ᵐb], [ⁿd], [ⁿz], [ᵑɡ]. Prenasalization is confirmed until at least Korean textbook Ch'ŏphae Sinŏ (첩해신어) written in 1618. Prenasalization was lost somewhen during Edo period.

In 1600 じ, ぢ, ず, づ were distinct: [ʑi], [d͡ʑi], [zu], [d͡zu]. Distinction survives in south-western Japan. Read more (with map) in Yotsugana article.

In 1600 せ, ぜ were palatalized (probably [ɕe], [ʑe]) similarly to し, じ (probably [ɕi], [ʑi]).
Umpaku dialects and some other dialects retain palatalization of せ and ぜ.
According to analysis by Frellesvig (2010, pages 322-323) of Portuguese sources, all other consonants were also palatalized before [i], [e]. Examples:
mi み = [mʲi]
me め = [mʲe]
In standard Modern Japanese, [i] causes palatalization of preceding consonant, but [e] does not.

In 1600 は, ひ, ふ, へ, ほ had the same consonant [ɸ]: [ɸa], [ɸi], [ɸu], [ɸe], [ɸo]. (Morpheme-medially they were [wa], [wi], [u], [we], [wo] since second half of 10th century, and [wi] and [we] later merged with [i] and [je].)
In late 18th / early 19th century, [ɸa], [ɸe] and [ɸo] changed to [ha], [he], [ho], and [ɸi] changed to [çi].
Umpaku dialects retain pronunciation with [ɸ].

In 1600 there were [kʷa] and [gʷa] syllables (maybe only in Sino-Japanese vocabulary), spelt くわ, ぐわ, whose consonants were labiovelarized.
(EMJ also had at least [kʷe] and [gʷe] syllables, but they lost their labiovelarization before around 1300 morpheme-initially and before around 1100 morpheme-medially. In EMJ, there was 1 native Japanese word with [kʷe] syllable, verb kʷe- (Conclusive kʷeru) (contraction from OJ kuwe-) (modern ker-, 蹴る).)
[kʷa] and [gʷa] merged with [ka] and [ga] in late 19th century.
Umpaku dialects retain [kʷa] and [gʷa].

In 1600 there was syllable-final consonant [t] (not followed by vowel, and not part of [t̚t] cluster still existing in Modern Japanese), spelt つ or sometimes ち. Besides Portuguese sources, this consonant is attested in some Japanese sources by spelling variants with specific hentaigana. This consonant was mostly limited to Sino-Japanese vocabulary, but was also found in variant shapes of native words, whose regular shapes had final vowels.
Examples from Portuguese sources mentioned by Frellesvig (2010, pages 316-318):
fotnet suru "get fever" (発熱)
connit "today" (今日)
ximot "cane, rod (used in criminal punishment)" (~ [ɕimoto])
carafit "big box, lit. Chinese chest" (~ [karaɸitu])
tetdai "help" (~ [tet͡sudai])
In later Modern Japanese, [t] acquired epenthetic vowel and turned into [t͡ɕi] or [t͡su].

In early Modern Japanese, nominalizer no developed, from use of no as complementizer in adnominal clauses (Frellesvig (2010, pages 362-365)).

Contracted forms of copulae developed in Late Middle Japanese:
naru → na
de aru → dya [d͡za], dea (and marginally attested da)
There was tendency for dya to be used in main clauses, and na adnominally, but both could be used in either function. Examples from Frellesvig (2010, page 342):
wasi wa syotyoo no ɔɔ dya (Esopo)
kono koto wa asa-kara-nu fusin dya fodo ni (Esopo)
kata-me na sika
kono mono wa nao isyu ga gozaru ge-na (Feiqe)
In Modern Japanese, da and na have become restricted to only conclusive function and attributive function respectively.

In 1600, bigrade / nidan (二段) verb classes were still were alive. Verbs from these classes migrated to monograde / ichidan (一段) classes during Modern Japanese.
Migration started with short verbs, and around 1600 some verbs had variant forms, e.g. ɸe- "pass": ɸuru ~ ɸeru.

In 1600 there were 2 n-irregular verbs. In Modern Japanese they migrated to regular consonant-stem verbs (godan (五段)):
inuru (往ぬる・去ぬる) → inu (往ぬ・去ぬ)
ɕinuru (死ぬる) → ɕinu (死ぬ)

In Old Japanese (700 - 800), Conjectural/Suppositional form (often called Volitional for Modern Japanese) of verbs was regularly formed by suffix [-am-] (initial vowel [a] of this suffix was elided for vowel-stem verbs), followed by Conclusive suffix [-u]. In Early Middle Japanese, this [m-u] developed into nasal vowel [ũ], which later lost nasality and changed to [u], which later underwent monophthongization with preceding vowel using rules described in point 3.
Developments until 1600:
kak- "write" (書く): [kakamu] → [kakaũ] → [kakau] → [kakɔː]
ake- "open" (開くる, modern 開ける): [akemu] → [akeũ] → [akeu] → [akʲoː]
mi- "see" (見る): [mimu] → [miũ] → [miu] → [mʲuː]
se- "do" (する): [semu] → [seũ] (/ [ɕeũ]) → [seu] (/ [ɕeu]) → [ɕoː]
ko- "come" (來る): [komu] → [koũ] → [kou] → [koː]
In Modern Japanese, shape and formation of Volitional for vowel-stem verbs was changed from above (etymologically regular) mechanism to addition of suffix [-joː] to stem of verb (increasing number of morae by 1):
ake- "open" (開くる, modern 開ける): [akʲoː] → [akejoː]
mi- "see" (見る): [mʲuː] → [mijoː]
se- "do" (する): [ɕoː] → [ɕijoː]
ko- "come" (來る): [koː] → [kojoː]
In Modern Japanese, for consonant-stem verbs, only regular phonological change described in point 3 was applied to Volitional:
kak- "write" (書く): [kakɔː] → [kakoː]

Past Conjectural/Suppositional [kemu] (けむ) lost productivity in Modern Japanese, but is supposedly still used in old-fashioned writing and in some dialects.

In 1600 paradigm of Negative auxiliary of verbs was more irregular and suppletive than in Early Middle Japanese (Frellesvig (2010, pages 336-337)). Several new forms were developed, their etymologies are all unknown and they all went out of use in standard Modern Japanese (but are retained dialectally).
Main forms of Negative (with examples for verbs kak- (書く) and ake- (開くる, modern 開ける)):
Nonpast Continuative -(a)zu (← EMJ -(a)zu) (e.g. kakazu, akezu)
Nonpast Conclusive/Attributive -(a)nu (← EMJ -(a)nu) (e.g. kakanu, akenu)
Nonpast Conditional -(a)zuwa, -(a)zunba (e.g. kakazuwa / kakazunba, akezuwa / akezunba)
Nonpast Provisional -(a)neba (e.g. kakaneba, akeneba)
Nonpast Concessive -(a)nedomo (e.g. kakanedomo, akenedomo)
Past Continuative -(a)nande (~ -(a)nandari) (e.g. kakanande (~ kakanandari), akenande (~ akenandari))
Past Conclusive -(a)nanda (e.g. kakananda, akenanda)
Past Attributive -(a)nanda (~ -(a)nandaru) (e.g. kakananda (~ kakanandaru), akenanda (~ akenandaru))
Past Exclamatory -(a)nandare (e.g. kakanandare, akenandare)
Past Conjectural -(a)nandarɔː (e.g. kakanandarɔː, akenandarɔː)
Past Provisional -(a)nandareba (e.g. kakanandareba, akenandareba)
Gerund -(a)ide (e.g. kakaide, akeide)

The gerund -ide is similar to the EMJ negative gerund -de, but any derivational relationship is unclear. A number of negative past tense forms (past -nanda, past conjectural -nandarɔɔ, past infinitive -nande, past provisional -nandareba) reflect a past negative auxiliary, -(a)nandar-, which came into use in the first half of LMJ. (...) Etymologically, -(a)nandar- seems to involve a combination of negative -(a)n- and the stative (past) auxiliary -(I)tar-, but the details of the composition of the form are entirely unclear.

Past -(a)nanda continued in use into 19th century.
Paradigm of Negative was completely replaced in standard Modern Japanese.



Sources:

Bjarke Frellesvig (2010) "A History of the Japanese Language"

Some notations adjusted to be more IPA-compatible.

What an amazing answer!

Judging from a reader for padres to learn Japanese back then, I would say that we would have trouble to understand it.

日本の言葉とヒストリアを習い知らんと欲する人のために世話にやわらげたる平家の物語 (Nifon no cotoba to Historia uo narai xiranto fossvrv fito no tameni xeva ni yavaragvetarv Feiqe no monogatari)


What is your intended pronunciation of /x/, /v/ and /q/, exactly? Also, surely they would not have had such a loanword as ヒストリア?

@KarlKnechtel - They mixed some Portuguese words.

@KarlKnechtel It’s written by Portuguese for Portuguese. I’m not sure of the pronunciation they intended, but I guess it’s like xe:シェ, v:ウ, qe:ケ.

If anything that looks surprisingly comprehensible, the only unusual word in that title is やわらげたる. The romaji only looks weird because it's using Portuguese spelling.

Yes, after adjusting for the Portuguese orthography of the time, the main pronunciation differences are: 1) modern /se/ was more like /ʃe/; 2) modern /h/ was /f/ (technically probably bilabial [ɸ]) for all vowels, not just /u/; 3) there may have been more words pronounced with what sounds like final consonants.  For #3, modern Japanese has です which sounds like /des/, with a final /s/. If the Nippo Jisho is accurate, some words had final /t/, such as 賢哲: modern kentetsu, Nippo qentet.

I downvoted this answer, because it focuses on the orthography of a particular transcription scheme used by the Portuguese, and not the spoken language as asked for by the OP.

@jogloran This source is the base of research for “what did actual speech sound like” back then.

If you wish to dig into the source itself for evidence that answers the question, then I will retract my downvote. But as it stands, you've quoted the title of the reader, which, to be honest, is at least 95% completely understandable to me (as a speaker of modern Japanese).

@jogloran Fair enough.
